# Replace Function - Handling single quotes and forward slashes in SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I want to replace some data from my database where single quotes and slashes are present.

The line below is exactly how it appears in the database and I only want to remove *'F/D',* from the record.

```
('P/P','F/D','DFC','DTP')
```

Been using varations of

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, '''F/D,''', '')
WHERE RECORDID = XXXXX
```

Also been using varations of

```
UPDATE tablename SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, 'F/D,', '')
WHERE RECORDID = XXXXX
```

Seems like it should be a simple fix but I haven't had any luck yet - all suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: And how does your code not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your's doesn't work is because you aren't including the quotes. You are looking for `F/D,` and `'F/D,'` and your data it is `'F/D',`.

If it's simply `'F/D'` from all values you want removed, then you also need to remove a comma and the quotes. This method removes `'F/D'` and then, any double commas (in case `'F/D'` is in the middle of the string).

```
declare @var varchar(64) = '(''P/P'',''F/D'',''DFC'',''DTP'')'

select replace(replace(@var,'''F/D''',''),',,',',')

--update tablename 
--set columnname = replace(replace(columnname,'''F/D''',''),',,',',')
--where RECORDID = 1324
```

If you want to replace the second element in the string, here is a way:

```
select 
        @var
         --find the location of the first comma
        ,charindex(',',@var,0)  
        --find the location of the second comma
        ,charindex(',',@var,charindex(',',@var) + 1)    
        --Put it all together, using STUFF to replace the values between this range with nothing
        ,stuff(@var,charindex(',',@var,0),charindex(',',@var,charindex(',',@var) + 1) - charindex(',',@var,0),'')
```

Comment: scsimon, select replace(replace(@var,'''F/D''',''),',,',',') worked - thanks!

Comment: No problem at all @RussellAlan

Answer (score 0):

Your first version should work fine if the comma is in the right place:

```
UPDATE tablename
    SET columnname = REPLACE(columnname, '''F/D'',', '')
    WHERE RECORDID = XXXXX;
```

Note that this will not replace `'F/D'` if it is the first or last element in the value.  If that is an issue, I would suggest that you ask another question.